# Python / configparser file data reading

Tags: python, configparser

I'm having some problems with reading data from file. I want to get properties from *.ini* data file to be red by the function, but *configparser* doesn't read it properly. I would be very grateful if someone could explain that is wrong. Thank you in advance!

**Function snippet**

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

def browseFiles():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = config['select']['dir'],
                                          title = config['select']['ttl'],
                                          filetypes = config['select']['ft'])
      
    # Change label contents
    label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+filename)
```

**my .ini file data**

```
[select]
#directory
dir = "home/"
#title
ttl = "Select a File"
#filetype
ft = (("Text files","*.txt*"),("all files","*.*"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nirmal Dey pointed out, `ConfigParser` will only return string values. You'd have to convert them to Python types using e.g. `ast.literal_eval`

FWIW, I have written a small package called [configdot](https://github.com/jjnurminen/configdot) for parsing INI files. It will automatically return Python types and also allows attribute-style access for config variables (e.g. `config.select.ft` in your case)

Comment: I love it @jussi, its very convenient

Comment: By the way where i need put st.literal_eval? In here filedialog.askopenfilename ?

Comment: You'd have to put it around the string-valued arguments. E.g. `filetypes = ast.literal_eval(config['select']['ft'])`

Comment: But if i use your package i don't need it right?

Answer (score 1):

`Config parsers do not guess datatypes of values in configuration files, always storing them internally as strings.`

Every key-value pair present in the .ini file would be parsed as a string.

Your `filedialog.askopenfilename` the function expects a tuple in the filetypes argument while you are giving it a string datatype.

Comment: @Dey Sorry, but I didn't understand correctly the last part

Comment: filetypes argument expects an iterator. It can not work with a stringified version of a tuple. if you wish to pass the filetype argument from your .ini file then you need to make a slight change in the .ini file.


```
ft[]=("Text Files", "*.txt")
ft[]=(""all files ", ".")
```

after it, the config parser would know that ft is a list and not a single string.